# Created user but I can't switch to new account

Tags: users, user-management

I created a new user using this command:

```
sudo adduser -system -home=/opt/odoo -group odoo
```

But I'm getting this error with comman `sudo su - odoo`:

```
This account is currently not available
```

how can I activate the account I just created?

Answer (score 1):

You created a system user. The default Shell in `/etc/passwd` is `/usr/sbin/nologin` – no login allowed.

Options

1. create a regular User
2. change the Entry in `/etc/passwd` towards e.g. `/bin/sh`